# Is there anyway to make more than one dummies variable at a time?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I am trying to dummy all categorical data at once I don't know it is possible or not if there's a way can you help me

Here's what I have tried

```
df['Gender'],df['Country'],df['State'],df['Mortgage'] = pd.get_dummies(df['Gender', 'Country', 'State', 'Mortgage'])
```

well, I know this will give an error but is there something that can do this job!!

Comment: Can you try `df1= pd.get_dummies(df[['Gender', 'Country', 'State', 'Mortgage']])` ?

Comment: also is possible add some sample data 2-3 rows and expected output?